# Animate different parts

Tags: modeling

I want to animate a lounger's legs in such way so they are folding together but I don't know how to make so only the legs are moving and not the rest of the lounger without separating the legs from the lounger.

I don't want to separate the legs because it looks weird when I subdivide the mesh.

Thanks in advance.

How I want them to fold:

[image]

When separate and subdivided (I don't want them to look like that):

[image]

Comment: Try to [rig](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/rigging/introduction.html) the mesh by creating an armature and positioning its parts adjacent to legs